# Diagnosis analytics

Tags: data-mining

I am studying an analytic use case concerning exceeding energy equipments detection. As a beginner in data analytics I am not sure how to begin to resolve this problem.
The use case is resumed as below :

- There is a list of 5 equipments. For each equipment we measured  the activation time  for each timestamp.
  For example :

> ```
>                 8h-10h   10h-12h   12h-14h   14h-16h   16h-18h 
> equipement 1     100      100       10        0         20 
> equipement 2     100      40        10        10        0 
> equipement 3     100      32        0         20        0 
> equipement 4     0        0         0         100      90 
> equipement 5     100      0         0         0         0
> ```

And also, I recorded for each timestamp if there in an exceeding energy or not :

> ```
>          8h-10h       10h-12h     12h-14h          14h-16h      16h-18h 
>         exceeding     exceeding   no exceeding     exceeding    no exceeding
> ```

My objective in this study is to detect which equipments  are responsible for exceeding energy.
Can you propose me some idea to analyze and resolve this problem?

Comment: how do you define "exceeding"? do you know the "threshold"? or it is a random thing, you can observe, but do not know why.

Comment: exceeding where the value > 100

Comment: why not just write a rule based "model", where >100 is exceeding, and you search the column to find which one is >100

Comment: I am lookinf for a methof more intelligent to find equipement

Comment: i have to say it is not clear what you are asking.. this may be the reason why someone else will give you advice like "go to read some math"...

Comment: Ok, I will reformulate my question, sorry :)